Looking for a modification of variable importance in ANCOVA-type glmm
This question is about a statistical concept I think should exist.  I would like to know if it has a name and hopefully an R package that will implement it.  It is related to variable importance/dominance but rather than considering the overall improvement of a model with variable inclusion, I’m interested in how it affects the estimation (precision and bias) of a key fixed factor in the model.  I can explain better with an example.
I am interested in estimating the change in insect abundance over time.  The data are counts of individuals at a light trap operated once a week for two years and then repeated 3 decades later. Taking one species as an example, and with a model containing just the main effect “Time”, I find no significant difference.  The estimate of the Time effect is 0.035 (given the log-link this is a 3.6% increase) but the s.e. of the estimate is 10 times this.
Much of the variability in catches is due to the seasonality of this species and the weekly sampling.  Adding a quadratic week-of-year component to the model makes a much better model, ΔAIC is -159 and the estimate of Time is now 0.25 (a 28% increase) but the s.e. (0.26) is about equal to the estimate so still not enough to claim an increase in this species.
Another variable that improves the model is air temperature (which affects insect flight activity) with a further ΔAIC of -18.  But now the estimate for change over Time is -0.76 (a 50% decrease) with a s.e. of 0.25.  The reason for this dramatic change of fortune is that average air temperatures have increased over the 3 decades – the increase in insect activity was masking a decrease in abundance.  Including temperature instead of seasonality has a ΔAIC of -125 so seasonality would be favoured over temperature by a stepwise procedure, but it is temperature that has the biggest influence on estimation of the Time effect.  Some aspects of this particular case would not arise if it were a designed experiment (and air temperature balanced across Time), but this is a real-world problem, and I cannot control the climate.
A further complication is that there is temporal autocorrelation in the residuals so using glmmTMB I included a random effect for autocorrelation (Ornstein-Uhlenbeck because there are some missing weeks and autocorrelation is positive).  The model would look like this:
model<-glmmTMB (spX ~ Time + week + I(week^2) + airT+ou(seq + 0 | group), data=datx, family=nbinom2)

The estimated autocorrelation is 0.61 and ΔAIC a further -18.  The Time effect is now -0.96 (a 62% decrease) but the s.e. has increased to 0.46 so the effect is larger but “less significant”.  Clearly these three components of the model (seasonality, temperature and autocorrelation) are all important (for somewhat different reasons) but there are other potential covariates (e.g. moon, cloud, wind, rain) that affect insect captures at a light trap and some will be balanced over Time (e.g. barometric pressure) but some may behave more like air temperature and their exclusion would leave bias in the estimate.
Is there a framework for assessing the relative utility of all these variables in obtaining precise and unbiased estimates of the Time effect?  How can I justify and quantify my advice to other entomologists that “you really should measure this covariate”.

I am not aware of a universally accepted standard framework specifically named for assessing variable importance within GLMMs, but there are methodologies and concepts from related fields that could be adapted:
Influence Analysis: While commonly used in simpler models, examining the influence of individual covariates on the estimation of fixed effects can be adapted to mixed models. This involves assessing changes in coefficient estimates and their precision when covariates are added or removed, which you've already started doing with the $\Delta AIC$ values
Conditional and Marginal $R^2$: These measures can provide insight into the variance explained by the fixed effects alone (conditional) and by the entire model including random effects (marginal). This could help quantify how much each covariate contributes to explaining variation in the response variable relative to the fixed effect of interest. The R package MuMIn implements these.
Multicollinearity Diagnostics: Checking for multicollinearity through variance inflation factors (VIFs) could help identify covariates that disproportionately influence the stability and interpretation of your fixed effect estimates. The R packages car and performanceprovide functionality to help with multicollinearity diagnostics and other model checking tasks
Path Analysis and Structural Equation Modeling (SEM): These approaches can provide a formal framework to analyse the direct and indirect effects of covariates on an outcome variable, thus helping disentangle complex relationships that might affect bias and precision. In R, the lavaan package is available for path analysis and structural equation modelling.
Shapley Regression Values: Borrowed from game theory and used in machine learning to assess feature importance, this method could potentially be adapted to statistical models to evaluate the contribution of each covariate to the predictive accuracy and stability of parameter estimates. In R, the package iml provides machine learning interpretability tools in R, including a Shapley value calculator which might be adapted for regression models.
Comment on Model Formulation: Regarding your model formulation:
model<-glmmTMB (spX ~ Time + week + I(week^2) + airT+ou(seq + 0 | group), data=datx, family=nbinom2)

, using random slopes but not random intercepts is unusual in many applied contexts where both random intercepts and slopes are modeled to account for non-independence within groups across the levels of the fixed effects. Omitting random intercepts might be justified if there's reason to believe that all groups start from the same baseline (which is rarely the case in ecological data), or it might be a model simplification to avoid overparameterisation given data constraints. However, typically, including at least random intercepts is advisable to account for between-group variability.

Lots to follow up here.  First problem, MuMIn will not work when I include the autocorrelation (crashes out of R with no error message).  Perhaps MuMIn doesn't understand the output from glmmTMB when random effects notation is used to specify autocorrelation, or maybe conditional and marginal R^2 are not at all sensible in this setting.

Re. your comment on Model Formulation, I may have misled you.  "group" is the same as "Time", not a new factor in the model but I should have been more careful.  I was following link.

I would like to focus on one detail only of Robert Long's nice answer (+1), namely the path-analysis part.
The bivariate effect of "time" appears to be (close to) zero. Controlling for temperature is obviously needed, as it is known that higher temperature causes more insect activity and, hence, higher counts. Omitting temperature as an explanatory variable would lead to a biased effect of time. Temperature acts here as a mediator of the time effect: time "causes" a rise in temperature (effect A, say), and temperature in turn causes higher insect activity/counts (effect B). Both A and B are positive effects, so the mediated effect of time on insect counts, being the product A * B, is also positive.
Besides the mediated or indirect effect of time, there is also a direct effect of time on the insect counts, which is the effect of time (effect C) controlled for temperature, which is negative! Meaning that if you select counts made at some fixed temperature, counts observed at later time points are lower. This direct effect is interesting obviously, as it decouples the time effect from the temperature influence.
Finally, the total (bivariate) effect of time is the sum of the positive mediated effect and the negative direct effect, or A * B + C, and this sum is (close to) zero, which is what you found. This is the result of A * B being almost equal to -C, for your data.
EDIT after comment
The above description of the mediation was meant to make it understandable why your bivariately estimated effect of time on the counts is close to zero. If you would run simple linear regressions, you could then see how this bivariate effect of time can be split into a direct and indirect effect. You would have to run two regressions then, lm(temperature ~ time) for effect A, and lm(insectcounts ~ temperature + time) for effects B and C. However, for the negative binomial model you used, the perfect equality of A * B + C with the bivariate effect of time will in general not hold (I should have said that too), but the mechanism would work similar, namely C being negative and A*B positive and hence the resulting bivariate effect being close to zero. A path diagram may be in order to illustrate the mediation mechanism, with the side note that the mediation equality is not perfect here.
Thanks for this example which shows that a thorough analysis can only be done with knowledge of the subject matter.

Really useful, thinking this through has made me realize that my dep var (catch) is not what I really want to measure (insect population size) but that is not practical.  Catch is the product of population and catchability, and temperature affects catchability (and possibly also population, but over a longer time scale).  Do I need to be using causal diagrams to understand confounding?  Also, can you explain where you get A B and C from the information I posted?  Don't you need the relationship between temperature and time?

Thanks for the upvote, Ben  [+1 to you too ]

@IMH I added a few lines to my answer. Hope this helps.
